# Checking if several columns in a panda dataframe coincide and labeling them in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have two dataframes in which some rows are the same. What I am trying to do is to check is any row has the same 3 values in 3 columns in the other dataframe, add a especific label to a column I created. The rows in each dataframe are not in the same order.

I tried the only way I could think of. I saw in another similar post about merging, but It didn't seem to work due to being the rows in diferent order.

```
for i in range((df.shape[0])):
    if df[i][0] and df[i][1] and df [i][3] == Bid.iterrow():
        df[i][4]= 'pep'
```

A toy set of the dataframe, to show how they are constructed:

```
2  SC_201916_S1             100   eur           5651.0  kr  Other
3  SC_201916_S1             100   aus           5651.0  Chi  Other
4  SC_201915_S1             45    io            5538.0  CH  Other


2  SC_201838       100      MW         23455.0    CHF/MW
3  SC_201829       100      MW         22345.0    CHF/MW
4  SC_201830       78       MW         21238.0    CHF/MW
```

I expected this code to check if columns 1,2 and 4 had the same value as the ones in the dataframe 'bid', to write 'pep' in the 5th column. It only said keyerror:0, but I don't get it, I'm not working with dictionaries.

Thanks in advance and sorr if this is to much of a noob question.

Comment: Can you post the 2 dataframe samples please (as text)?

Comment: Done! I don't know how to format it as a table thou...

Comment: In case anyone wondered, the first column which looks like an Id key repeats several times through the file.

Comment: As per your recommendation, I tried isin() method as this:                                                                                                     for i in range((df.shape[0])):
          if df.iloc[i].isin(df2):
              df.at[i, 4]= 'pep'                                                                                                                                                         but yields "value error, truth value is ambiguous"

Comment: So you found a solution now? I was a little confused about the exact output so couldnot post an answer

Comment: No, sorry. Not yet, but with isin looks promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution for you, using [pandas.DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

First let me create to dummy DataFrames to showcase how it works. We will join on first and second column. They are in "wrong order".

```
first = pd.DataFrame([['b', 'a', 'c'], [2, 1, 3], ['is', 'this', 'not_important']]).T
second = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'd'], [1, 4, 3], ['this', 'is', 'not_important']]).T
```

Then, to "flag" rows whose columns 0 and 1 appear with the same values in second column:

```
first['pep_col'] = np.where(first.merge(second, how='left', left_on=[0, 1], right_on=[0, 1], suffixes=('', '_other'))['2_other'].notna(), 'pep', 'not_pep')
```

Which allows us to mark with "pep" anything that was found in the second DataFrame.

---

Solution above assumes, that there are no duplicates in the second DataFrame on the columns you are interested in, i.e. that it either exists as a one-of or does not exist. Otherwise you need to drop duplicates too:

```
first['pep_col'] = np.where(first.merge(second, how='left', left_on=[0, 1], right_on=[0, 1], suffixes=('', '_other')).drop_duplicates(first.columns)['2_other'].notna(), 'pep', 'not_pep')
```

---

If you cannot assure that either of dataframes has no duplicates on important columns we can check for all rows from the first DataFrame if given row belongs to values in second DataFrame:

```
first['join_col'] = tuple(zip(first[0], first[1]))
second['join_col'] = tuple(zip(second[0], second[1]))
set(second['join_col'].tolist())
first['pep_col'] = np.where([val in set(second['join_col'].tolist()) for val in first['join_col'].tolist()], 'pep', 'no_pep')
```

Possibly you want to drop "join_col" from both DataFrames after flagging column creation.

Comment: WOW. It worked better than I hoped, I completely forgot to check for duplicates. I learned a lot with this solution, thank you!